# Media Library No Longer Displays Images

Tags: media-library

My media library suddenly stopped properly showing images. I've been running WP since June with no problems and then yesterday the Media Library stopped working. I didn't do any updates or install any plugins. I used it about an hour before with no problems and then went to use it again and it was broken. Here's what I know:

- the media is still there. If I follow the direct link the image still shows just fine in the browser.
- All images show fine on the blog posts. No harm there. They still exist on the server.
- I can still upload an image. It just directly goes to the broken image default thumbnail view.
- I CAN NOT insert images from the media library into a new post. When you look at the code the image path is missing.
- I've disabled all plugins and it had no affect.
- I've researched this issue on Google but have not been able to find a solution or a problem that is exactly as I'm having.

Update: I opened my site using the iphone Wordpress app and the media displays properly via the app. It does not display correctly if I log in on my phone via the browser.

Here is what my view looks like (note: many had this problem where the file name displayed along with the default image, but mine does not do that)
[image: screenshot of my media gallery]

Comment: Look in your browser's error console for javascript errors.

Comment: This is what comes up in the console:

`load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.8.1:9 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
upload.php:1564 Uncaught ReferenceError: QTags is not defined
    at upload.php:1564
(anonymous) @ upload.php:1564`